# Disable resizing of a form

Tags: c++, qt

I want to disable resizing my form - here is what I have tried. 
I have changed the resize policy of the form to the following
HorizontalPolicy:Fixed
VerticalPloicy: Fixed

I have also tried the following

```
Form *w = new Form(); 
w->setFixedSize(w->size());
w->show();
```

But the form still gets resized by dragging the corners. Any suggestions ?

Comment: This is really strange, what you've tried should work. If you are developing on Windows, try with `w->setWindowFlags(Qt::MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint)`

Comment: @NemanjaBoric Unfortunately that doesnt work either. Maybe because I am using a form here. Instead I should be using a dialog.I dont think forms can be disabled from resizing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It definitely has to be possible.

Firstly you should know, that before window is actually shown it has no information of it's size - so size will probably return 0 (or invalid; or anything ;) ) at this point - it would probably mess up entire sizing and is therefore silently rejected. I would try

```
Form *w = new Form();
//w->ensurePolished();
w->setFixedSize(w->sizeHint());
w->show();
```

Size hint should have correct value no matter what. [QWidget::ensurePolished()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#ensurePolished) might be necessary here, but I recommend trying first without it - if it works, why complicate things?

If it still doesn't work, then you can simply try overriding `resizeEvent()` and setting **the only right size** for your widget if user resizes it to anything else. This will still give user an illusion of resize-ability (cursors changes on the edges and so on), so it's really the last option.

EDIT:

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QWidget>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QWidget w;
    w.setFixedSize(500,500);
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Result: widget cannot be resized. So it is not change to QMainWindow that helped - oat least on my system a simple widget can do it too ;)

Comment: Just to be sure i just created a new project, with new default QMainWindow, removed status bar (having separate resize handle), and **after** `setupUi()` I added `setFixedSize(sizeHint());` - and my windows doesn't size - not even showing sizing cursor when hovering borders. My system WIndows 7, Qt 4.7.4 (32bit).

Comment: Well I am using QT plugin for VS2010. Created  new UI class derived from QWidget Base Class. Incase its a main window its derived from `QMainWindow`. My ui class inherits from `QWidget`

Comment: Even if my UI Inherits from QMainWindow I get the same issue

Comment: After inheritng from QMainWindow and using `w->setFixedSize(w->size());` that fixed the problem